# How to retrieve the html tag attributes in jquery and javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, html-table

I have tried  the following code to draw a table from an array and retrieve the attribute id from the rows. Any suggestions would be appreciated immensely.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$.get('php/php.php', function(data){
    $.each(data, function(index, value){
    $('table').append(
        "<tr id='someid'>"
            +"<td>"+value.ticker+"</td>"
            +"<td>"+value.bid+"</td>"
        +"</tr>");
    }); 
}, "json");

$('tr').click(function(){
var id = $(this).attr("id");
alert(id);

}) 

});
```

Comment: you're generating multiple `<tr>`s that all have the same ID; that is not valid markup.

Comment: sorry mu mistake that was suppose to be "<tr id=\""+value.ticker+"\">"

Answer (score 3):

You are binding click events to elements that do not yet exist, since they are constructed in an asynchronous callback. Instead of using `click`, use `on`. Since your table is not dynamically constructed, you can attach the `on` handler to that.

```
$('table').on('click', 'tr', function () {
    ...
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

also, you're generating multiple `<tr>`s that all have the same ID; that is not valid markup.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough. The code you've sent me works and your explanation of the problem clarified the issue. Thanks...

Comment: @byteME it may be a good idea to give your table a class or id to select on as well so you do not accidently bind this click handler to future tables.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are dynamically injecting the new content to the DOM, It is not aware of the click event you bounded. so your click event won't work.

Solution : **use jQuery [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**

```
$(document).on("click","tr",function(){
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
  alert(id);
})
```

This method is available from **jQuery 1.7+** version. If you are using an older version , you may consider using [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

As of jQuery 1.7, the `.live()` & `.delegate()` method is deprecated. use `on` method.

Comment: The `on` is missing from the code.  I'd edit, but because it's only a 2-character change it gets rejected.

Comment: Because `.on` doesn't automatically work with new DOM elements as you seemed to imply. You have to write it in a certain way.

Comment: @Blazemonger: Fair enough  ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine but you have just missed the semicolon at the end of tr click event

```
$('tr').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    alert(id);
});
```

This will alert the id of the tr if the tr id is unique

Make Sure that in any syntax error will not allow jquery code execution.